# Getting a row index in a JTable using only a value included in the row?

Tags: java, swing, indexing, jtable, row

In Java, is it possible in a JTable to obtain a row's index by looking for a specified value contained in that row? I am using a custom table model. For example, consider a table with three columns and three rows:

```
Row 1 = A, B, C
Row 2 = D, E, F
Row 3 = G, H, I
```

If all I know is that there is a value of "F" somewhere in the table, how can I find out the index of the row where the value "F" is?

Comment: yes is possible, no coding or performance issue, for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, with (`I am using a custom table model`) this info & code is most important for proper suggestion

Comment: Are those values unique in the table?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If table model is available, a brute-force way is to loop it by row and column and compare the given value(say, 'F') with the result of `getValueAt(row, column)`. Sample code:

```
 int getRowByValue(TableModel model, Object value) {
    for (int i = model.getRowCount() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        for (int j = model.getColumnCount() - 1; j >= 0; --j) {
            if (model.getValueAt(i, j).equals(value)) {
                // what if value is not unique?
                return i;
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Damn, you were faster with your answer. :)

Comment: This is perfect, thank you good sir. The values will all be unique, as they will increment the alphabet

Comment: Thanks!

I made a little change because this will throw a NullPointerException if there is an empty cell.

I changed
`if (model.getValueAt(i, j).equals(value)) {`
to
`if (model.getValueAt(i, j) != null && model.getValueAt(i, j).equals(value)) {`
and now empty cells are no longer a problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
 private int returnRowIndexForValue(final String value) { 
      for (int i = 1; i <= table.getRowCount(); i++)
           for(int j = 1; j <= table.getColumnCount(); j++)
                if (table.getValueAt(i, j).equals(value))
                     return i;
 }
```

Comment: column and row are 0-based, instead of 1-based.

Comment: Minor out of bounds bug, but I think he got the idea. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just in case if there are `multiple rows` that are containing the value then return the return the `Integer List.`

```
private List<Integer> getRowIndexesOfValue(String value, JTable table) {

   List<Integer> rowNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

   for(int rowCount = 0; rowCount < table.getRowCount(); rowCount++) {
      for(int columnCount = 0; columnCount < table.getColumnCount(); columnCount++) {
          if(table.getvalueAt(rowCount, columnCount).toString().equals(value)) {
             rowNumbers.add(rowCount);
             break;  
          }
       }
    }
    return rowNumbers;
}
```