# String equals not working on Object

Tags: java, arrays, string, object, netbeans

```
    Object[] abc = { "products" };
    methodName(model2, abc);
```

I initialized an object and called the method :

```
public int methodName(TableModel model, Object value) {
    for (int i = model.getRowCount()-1; i >= 0; --i) {
    int j = 0; //first column I need

        System.out.println("a "+model.getValueAt(i, j)); //a products
        //this case RowCount was 1 (tested with println) which also means for loop is only once executed

        if (model.getValueAt(i, j).equals(value)) {
            return i;
        }
    }

return -1;
}
```

It always returns -1 although it should return i (0)

so why is .equals not working

Comment: You're trying to compare a single element (I guess) with an array. That's never going to return true...

Comment: This is what happens when you use a statically typed language without taking advantage of... the type system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So maybe try this:

```
Object    abc = { "products" };
```

Don't make `abc` an array.

But if it MUST be an array in the big picture, put `[...]` onto each `value` reference in the method. E.g., `value[0]`.

Comment: Object    abc = { "products" }; = illegal init for Object .... anyway .equals(value[0]) solved it... thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You are passing an array as the second argument to `methodName` and then you check if that array is `equals` to `model.getValueAt(i, j)`. Regardless of what `model.getValueAt(i, j)` returns, it can't be `equals` to that array, since arrays use the default implementation of `equals` (from `Object` class) which compares the object references.

Comment: Is there any way to fix it? The method i found here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14196974/getting-a-row-index-in-a-jtable-using-only-a-value-included-in-the-row